# What are your drywall/cement board/framing flatness tolerances for tile supporting walls?

Tags: drywall, tile, framing, cement-board

What are your drywall/cement board/framing flatness tolerances for tile supporting walls?
I am rebuilding half of a frame and it is a challenge to bring all the studs in the same plane. I do know about the tricks used to straighten studs but I am thinking there must be some tolerances in this respect

Update:
this is related to this thread.
[Can I use corner brackets to rebuild a wall frame that has the horizontal 2x4s extended in an adjacent room?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/207990/can-i-use-corner-brackets-to-rebuild-a-wall-frame-that-has-the-horizontal-2x4s-e)
I build my second half of the frame and now I am trying to align it with the existing and it seems to be complex since the top and the bottom plate could be aligned using a long level as straight edge but then studs might not be in the same plan with the other half that is already there.
I am using a vertical laser and double checking with the 8' straight edge-level

Update2:
this guy is doing it using thinset. Is this normal? (you can call this floating the cement board I guess)
https://youtu.be/Fls1asNV9ug?t=1141

Update3: this guy is floating the tiles instead
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tZrczG_H_U&ab_channel=VancouverCarpenter

Comment: I don't use drywall for tile. Given the expense and labor of installing tile, the slight upcharge for using proper backerboard is a minuscule investment in having a proper foundation for the job.

Comment: Agree with Ecnerwal in the use of an appropriate backer board.  If you're worried about straightening studs, use the steel ones.

Comment: Cementboard is ok?  I want to make sure the studs are     in the same plane but it is not perfect

Comment: Yes. Unless your walls are severely curved, the rigidity of the cement board, the "depth" of the adhesive, size of the tiles, etc. should eat up any slight unevenness from the studs. It will come out perceptibly flat. Otherwise you need to replace or shim the studs I'd guess. Post some picture of the existing studs and maybe include some way of seeing the variation in the picture (straight edge or something) so we can see what you're dealing with.

Comment: see the update. Re: re the adhesives eating up the uneveness -this is why I asked, I suspected that the adhesive could be used to compensate that but I was not sure how much ... some docs on the net are saying 1/4" for 10' but not more than 1/16'' for 12" but those are theoretical standards probably

Comment: He is wet shimming with kerdi foam board which uses a specific screw and washer combo, listen to all that led up to that point in the video. It is also a fairly advanced technique since you'll have to check flatness and plumbness on the fly

Comment: did you watch that last video? He is not floating the tiles, hes the drywaller fixing the flatness of the wall next to the tile

Comment: I might be mixing the terms, to me floating means using more or less filling material to even/flat the surface. I think he is using the term
Yes I watched part of it but since I am at the framing level I am trying to deal with this at this level

Comment: the tiler installed cbu of equal thickness to the drywall next to the tile, they did not address the flatness of the drywall install next to the tile, that is why the tile and schluter edge profile is straight while the drywall is not

Comment: yes I could see that, I was interested in how he worked around the curvy drywall not in how he got there :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use drywall cardboard shims or sistered studs to bring the studs into plane. TCNA says 1/4" deviation over 10'. If using large format tile, trying to level with thinset after will take way longer and be more frustrating than the time it would take to make sure the walls are straight and plumb

Edit: Since you like Sal youtube videos this is the one you want https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PCUWkbG060s

Comment: yes your answer seems to be right but I was wondering if the cement board will in fact hide small imperfections

Comment: define small, it will follow the contours of the studs if you are wondering so if the studs are out of plane the cement board will be wavy or curved once they are screwed in.

Comment: will follow if you screw the cement very tight but I am guessing the board has some rigidity by itself and it can stay flat if not forced to follow the studs

Comment: you won't be able to embed the screw heads if you try to leave a gap behind the boards

Comment: you can predrill that like you would do with wood

Comment: Go ahead and try to predrill and countersink the CBU screws

Comment: hey I am learning here :-))